# Find where a NumPy array is equal to any value in a list of values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of integers and want to find where that array is equal to any value in a list of multiple values.

This can easily be done by treating each value individually, or by using multiple "or" statements in a loop, but I feel like there must be a better/faster way to do it. I'm actually dealing with arrays of size `4000 x 2000`, but here is a simplified edition of the problem:

```
fake = arange(9).reshape((3,3))

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

want = (fake==0) + (fake==2) + (fake==6) + (fake==8)

print want 

array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

What I would like is a way to get `want` from a single command involving `fake` and the list of values `[0, 2, 6, 8]`.

I'm assuming there is a package that has this included already that would be significantly faster than if I just wrote a function with a loop in Python.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The function [numpy.in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) seems to do what you want. The only problems is that it only works on 1d arrays, so you should use it like this:

```
In [9]: np.in1d(fake, [0,2,6,8]).reshape(fake.shape)
Out[9]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

I have no clue why this is limited to 1d arrays only. Looking at its [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L284), it first seems to flatten the two arrays, after which it does some clever sorting tricks. But nothing would stop it from unflattening the result at the end again, like I had to do by hand here.

Comment: Hmm. I wrote this very simple function to do this job: 

 `def EqualsAny(ar,vals):
         out=zeros(ar.shape,dtype=bool)
         for val in vals:
                 out+=(ar==val)
         return out`

I thought that `numpy.in1d` would be faster, but it actually takes longer (for same result): 

 `In [11]: %timeit EqualsAny(badlabels,smallnum)
 1 loops, best of 3: 519 ms per loop
 In [7]: %timeit in1d(badlabels, smallnum).reshape(badlabels.shape)
 1 loops, best of 3: 871 ms per loop`

 Shouldn't `numpy.in1d` be way faster since it's written in C? Am I not using `%timeit` properly?

Comment: No, `in1d` is not written in c but in python, see the link to the source code I gave. It uses various numpy functions like `sort`, which should hopefully be written in C. It even has some optimized algorithm for when `vals` is short, which is pretty similar to your solution (but with `|=` in stead of `+=`). I don't know why your version is faster, this might depend on the length of both inputs.

Answer (score 16):

#### NumPy 0.13+

As of NumPy v0.13, you can use [`np.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), which works on multi-dimensional arrays:

```
>>> element = 2*np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2))
>>> element
array([[0, 2],
       [4, 6]])
>>> test_elements = [1, 2, 4, 8]
>>> mask = np.isin(element, test_elements)
>>> mask
array([[ False,  True],
       [ True,  False]])
```

#### NumPy pre-0.13

The accepted answer with `np.in1d` works only with 1d arrays and requires reshaping for the desired result. This is good for versions of NumPy before v0.13.

Answer (score 5):

@Bas's answer is the one you're probably looking for.  But here's another way to do it, using numpy's `vectorize` trick:

```
import numpy as np
S = set([0,2,6,8])

@np.vectorize
def contained(x):
    return x in S

contained(fake)
=> array([[ True, False,  True],
          [False, False, False],
          [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

The con of this solution is that `contained()` is called for each element (i.e. in python-space), which makes this much slower than a pure-numpy solution.